# Training on points with the Delta Rule in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I've create two classes of points by this code

```
clf;
%# random points

N = 1000;

a1=-1; b1=4;
a2=-4; b2=4;

x1 =  a1 + (b1-a1).*rand(N,1);
y1 =  a2 + (b2-a2).*rand(N,1);

x2 =  a1 + (b1-a1).*rand(N,1);
y2 =  a2 + (b2-a2).*rand(N,1);

hold all;

% Plot line y=-3/2*x+3
t = -1:.1:4;
z = -3/2*t+3;
plot(t,z)

n=300;

x1new=zeros(n,1);
y1new=zeros(n,1);
error1=zeros(n,1);
x2new=zeros(n,1);
y2new=zeros(n,1);
error2=zeros(n,1);

p1=rand(N,1); %  make error distribution for class 1

d1=0;
d2=0;
i=1;
 while d1<n  && i<N
   if (3*x1(i)+2*y1(i)<=6)  
       if p1(i) > 0.2
    d1=d1+1; 
    x1new(d1)=x1(i);
    y1new(d1)=y1(i); 
    error1(d1)=0; 
    plot(x1new(d1), y1new(d1),'-bs', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerSize',5)
       else
    d2=d2+1; 
    x2new(d2)=x1(i);
    y2new(d2)=y1(i);   
    error2(d2)=1; 
    plot(x2new(d2), y2new(d2),'-bs', 'MarkerFaceColor','r', 'MarkerSize',5)
       end  
   end
   i=i+1;
p2=rand(N,1); %  make error distribution for class 2
   if (3*x2(i)+2*y2(i)>6)  
       if p2(i) > 0.2
    d2=d2+1; 
    x2new(d2)=x2(i);
    y2new(d2)=y2(i); 
    error2(d2)=0; 
    plot(x2new(d2), y2new(d2),'-bs', 'MarkerFaceColor','r', 'MarkerSize',5)
       else
    d1=d1+1; 
    x1new(d1)=x2(i);
    y1new(d1)=y2(i);   
    error1(d1)=1; 
    plot(x1new(d1), y1new(d1),'-bs', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerSize',5)
       end  
   end
   i=i+1;
 end

 % Export to workplace
 assignin('base', 'Class1', [x1new,y1new,error1]);
 assignin('base', 'Class2', [x2new,y2new,error2]);
```

Here is the result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBK8D.png

Each class shall have 300 points.  The generated data is not linearly separable—20% of each class violating the linear separability.

But, now i must work with Delta Rule:

1. Using a perceptron, do the training on 200 points with the Delta Rule (Widrow-Hoff) to determine the weights and bias, and classify the remaining 100 points.
2. Using an adaline, do the training on 200 points with the Delta Rule (Widrow-Hoff) to determine the weights and bias, and classify the remaining 100 points.

*For each type of units, plot the graph showing the speed of convergence (the Mean Square Error in the vertical axis against the number of examples in training in the horizontal axis,)

*For each type of units, plot the graph showing the ratio (the percentage) of correctly classified examples against the number of examples in the training set (use 100 examples for learning and classify the 200 remaining—compute the percentage of the correctly classified data; then use 125 examples for training and classify the 175 remaining; use 150 for training and classify the 150 remaining; use 175 for training and classify the 125 remaining; use 200 for training and classify the 100 remaining)

Can you help me to do with Delta Rule in Matlab?

Comment: nobody can help me to figure out how to do the problem?

Comment: Have you seen this?http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26696-deltarule

Comment: But i need to define some parameter for the function.

Comment: This is your homework. This means YOU have to do it.

Comment: i means that i need someone figure out me some step to do this work. To be honest, it is not my homework, and i have little knowledge about Neutral Network, just a programmer need a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will Dwinnell made [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26696-deltarule) for DeltaRule learning and suggests possible parameters to input:

```
% B = DeltaRuleBatchTrain(X,Y,LearningRate,MaximumPasses,MinimumWeightChange,B0)
%
% B                    = Discovered coefficients
%
% X                    = Predictors (exemplars in rows, variables in columns)
% Y                    = Target variable (0/1 values)
% LearningRate         = Learning rate                             (try 0.05)
% MinimumWeightChange  = Minimum change in weight norm to continue (try 0.01)
% MaximumPasses        = Maximum number of training passes         (try 50)
% B0                   = Initial guess for coefficients (optional, NaN for none)
```

He gives the following example (which I've modified to work with the data you created:

```
% Generate some random data
X = [Class1; Class2]  %Now 600x3
Y = ones(size(X,1),1);
Y(1:size(Class1,1)) = 0;

% Train single neuron model using delta rule
B = DeltaRule(X,Y,0.05,0.01,50);

% Recall using discovered model
Z = Logistic(B(1) + X * B(2:end));

% Measure resubstitution accuracy
mean(Y == (Z > 0.5))
```

Comment: i've added some requirement, and it is very nice if you can help to extend it.

Comment: and what about perceptron and adaline?

Comment: Did you see how in his example he has a Logistic.m and he calls it inside DeltaRule.m? You'll replace that with your perceptron or adaline function.